# Dynamically adding two RadioButtons and a regular Button to a row

Tags: c#, dynamic, radio-button

I am trying to dynamically add two radiobuttons and a regular button to each row.  I have tried using this.Controls.AddRange and this.Controls.Add, however both have each button on its own row.  What would I do to have them all on the same row?

Here is my code:

```
        AddRow();



        RadioButton jumper = new RadioButton();
        RadioButton shortPin = new RadioButton();
        jumper.Text = "Jumper";
        shortPin.Text = "Short";
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { shortPin, jumper});

        cellIndex++;
```

Code for AddRow

```
        public bool AddRow()
    {
        bool retval = true;
        this.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute,20));
        this.RowCount = this.RowStyles.Count;
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: row of what?...same y axis of the form,another control?...

Comment: same y axis for all buttons

Comment: yes but y axis of the form or another control?

Comment: then the answer presented so far should have solved....

Comment: can u present more code,to see how u add ,where u call it and so on please?

Comment: then the problem is "mostly" instead of this.Controls u have to do this.yourtableLayoutPanel.Controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Location` of the controls.

inorder to keep the controls on the same row you need to set the same Y-Axis for both radio buttons.

Try This:

```
RadioButton jumper = new RadioButton();
jumper.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20);//x,y axis
jumper.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 30); //width,height
jumper.Text = "Jumper";

RadioButton shortPin = new RadioButton();

//change x-axis but keep same y-axis
shortPin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 20);
shortPin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 30); //width,height       
shortPin.Text = "Short";

this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { shortPin, jumper});
```

Comment: The RadioButtons are still in different rows

Comment: @Aaron: are maintaining same `y axis`(20 in my code) for both the controls?

Comment: Yes, same y axis for both

Comment: @Aaron: it works fine for me, from where you are triggering this function to add controls dynamically